# My followers keep dying! What am I doing wrong?

Tags: godus

My followers keep reproducing, and then leaving their huts. Shortly after they sit down on the ground and do nothing, and then shortly after that they drop dead!

[image]

Is this because of me not proving them with something that they need to survive or is the life cycle of these beings really short? Each time one of them dies I lose whatever the red number in the bottom left of the screen is (belief?)

My followers keep dying! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You aren't clicking on them enough!](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132305/what-effect-does-clicking-on-my-believers-have)

Or, more accurately, you might be clicking on their homes too much. Every time a villager comes out of their home to explore, they lose health. As they lose health, they weaken, and eventually die. That is what you're seeing when they sit down. They are in their final hours (seconds).

So make sure you click on them every once in a while! Especially if you see them sitting down. Or don't. You monster.

Comment: For the uninitiated, what does clicking on them actually do? Presumably extends their life somehow by... giving them orders? Petting them? Inspiring them with your noodly appendage? :) (*edit:* Ah, right, should read the link. So it's the noodle answer.)

Comment: Clicking on them restores their health to 100%. At which point their health will slowly dwindle unless they start to build a home or other item.

Answer (score 1):

Your walkers will wander around for a bit, looking for something to build. A home, a temple, an idol, etc. If they cannot find anything to build in time, they'll die. They lose health when they aren't sheltered, and they are not BUILDING.

You can restore their health to 100% by clicking on them.

The lesson is: don't create walkers unless you have a job for them.